# Creating Cloud Monitoring (Stack-Driver) metrics to measure requests counts to external api

Tags: .net, api, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've created a .net core API that calls an external API. I want to gather some metrics around the calls to the external API. The most important, right now, would be as getting the number of calls to that external API, at the last minute. The external API has rate limits and, in case the API hits the rate limit, I want to know which was the endpoint that was called more often.
I've tried to use Google Endpoints. It works fine but not for this purpose. It only allows me to get metrics on the endpoints of my API, not metrics related to the calls to the external API.
I've also tried to use Google Cloud Monitoring (aka Stackdriver). I had to create a custom metric and I've implemented the code suggested in the documentation (see https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) just on one of the endpoints (just for testing purposes). The problem is that there's a rate limit on custom metrics and I can't write data to a single time series faster than one point every 10 seconds, which means the custom metric won't work if more than one call is made to my API within 10 seconds, which will occur too often.

Has anyone implemented Stackdriver in a similar scenario like the one I need? How did you do that? Maybe this is not the best approach and there's a better way to do it.

Should I add logs instead and count the number of logs added in the last 10 minutes, to get the number of calls to the external API? This solution would definitely work to get the number of calls to the external API but it wouldn't allow me to get latency times and response types if I need to implement that in the future as well.

I've also tried to use Prometheus and Grafana to get this information and it worked ok, but I'm trying to use tools provided by Google only, as we're using the Google ecosystem.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I had to add a new label and assign a different value on each call to bypass the 10 seconds rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you found the answer:

It's true that you are can't write more than one data point/10 sec to a specific time series, however you can write different time series and that doesn't have any limit per time:

> If you want to write more than one point to the same time series, then
> use a separate call to the timeSeries.create method for each point.
> Don't write data to a single time series faster than one point each 10
> seconds. If you are adding data points to different time series, then
> there is no rate limitation.

Have you try that? I got it from the same [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#writing-ts) you saw.

Edit to complement the answer:
It's possible to avoid the rate limitation by writing the data points to different time series, in this case it was done by adding labels with different values.

Comment: Thanks @AdolfoOG for your answer. Yes, you're right. But I was using the code in this link, for testing purposes:

[link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/samples/monitoring-write-timeseries)

I was expecting this piece of code to be creating a new time series on each call:
`// Create a new time series using inputs.
            TimeSeries timeSeriesData = new TimeSeries();
            timeSeriesData.Metric = metric;
            timeSeriesData.Resource = resource;
            timeSeriesData.Points.Add(dataPoint);
`

It seems it is not.

Comment: I had to add a label with a different value on each call.